# How to change the display order of proportional circles in QGIS 2.10?

Tags: qgis, cartography, symbology, style, display

I'm making a map with proportional circles based on point data. I want the biggest circles to be displayed below the others and the tiniest circles above. Unfortunately the default view is different:

[image: map screenshot]

Is it possible to change the display setting of proportional circles in QGIS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In *Layer Properties > Style*, there should be an **Advanced** button which has the option **Symbol Levels**. Here you can define which symbol should have higher priority when displayed.

*Note that I used QGIS 2.8.2-Wien to find this option so there should be something very similar for QGIS 2.10*.

Comment: It works and it is the same option and path in 2.10. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @jeremyg - Brilliant buddy! Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 3):

are you tried for invert the symbol? so lowest will be on top and highest will be on bottom

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It actually doesn't work, because it inverts the thematic analysis (the population classified in 5 classes) but has no effects on the circles.